# How to center UILabel with mutliple lines of text in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I want to programmatically center a label with multiple lines of text. I've added it to the following constraints, but it's just displayed on a single line! How can I want it to display multiple lines without running over the boundaries of the screen?

```
let noResults = UILabel()

noResults.text = self.emptyMessage
noResults.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

noResults.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
noResults.textAlignment = .center
noResults.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 20.0)!
noResults.numberOfLines = 0
noResults.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

noResults.sizeToFit()


noResults.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
noResults.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(noResults)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noResults, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: noResults.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noResults, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: noResults.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)


NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yConstraint, xConstraint])
```

Comment: Add a constraint to limit the width

Comment: If you add this as an Answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add a Width constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with Storyboard , just give the width constraints to the **UILabel** and in Attribute inspector make **Line** property to ZERO (0).

[image: snapShot]

Comment: I want to programmatically center a label. It doesn't exist in the storyboard therefore.